# I want to put Ubuntu Linux on my Windows 8 laptop, but it only has 100 Gigabyte SSD, will it be viable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, ssd

I have a Lenovo Yoga Pad i5. I use it for gaming, work, watching movies and coding. It is my main machine. However I am getting quite bored of Windows 8, and would like to install Ubuntu.

How much space should I allocate for Ubuntu? I am not sure how I am going to be using it yet, but probably mostly for coding and just messing around. Also, would allocating more space hinder my gaming and other tasks on Windows? I usually just play LoL on this laptop, and I get a decent framerate of about 40-50fps. Would I see a framerate drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you shouldn't be using more than 30GB for Ubuntu(let's say 20-25GB). And no, it doesn't affect your Windows at all, except, obviously, you have less space for it.

Unless you already have 20-30GB unpartitioned space, I'd recommend using [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) for freeing up space, so you can select "Install alongside Windows" option when installing Ubuntu. Manual partitioning in setup is not recommended if you had no prior experience with Ubuntu or Linuxes in general.

Enjoy Ubuntu!

P.S. if you get curious(I know I did), don't try running LoL in Ubuntu through Wine or any other program - it really messy, and usually doesn't work.

**EDIT**: P.P.S. You can use shared NTFS partition to share data between OSes, Ubuntu can see Windows partitions. Just remember it doesn't work other way around. So if you don't plan using much Ubuntu-native stuff, you can put 1 storage partition, and small partition for Ubuntu. For coding you can use Code::Blocks or NetBeans (or some other IDE, just mentioning the ones I most used) natively on Ubuntu, just remember, except if you are writing java, you can't run same program you wrote on both OSes. For C/C++/Pascal(idk about other languages),  you can write once-**compile** anywhere.

ok, I went offtopic, I'll stop now. Ask if you need anything.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use the GParted Live CD for this (even though it is a fantastic resource for many other cases).  For the OP, I would highly suggest they use the built in windows disc utility to "shrink" the space.  It is also worth mentioning to them they may need [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to help with Grub working with UEFI (standard on most Windows 8 stickered laptops).

Comment: There is a ext2/3/4 driver for Windows (write access to ext4 is considered experimental at best), but the NTFS driver for Linux is a lot more mature.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is light OS while run in less memory you can run nice and perfectly in 10gb space,so according to you SSD configuration you can install ubuntu at 18-20gb sufficient and don't forget to create swap memory in case of you computer ram eats up by process the swap plays role...
I would prefer you to install linux mint in case of ubuntu because it is light and doesn't cause trouble..